# What will happen in SIP if both parties send INVITE to each other at same time

Tags: sip

"What will happen in SIP if both parties send INVITE to each other at same time"

1. What will be the behavior in the above case?
2. Which call will Process?

Comment: This is offtopic, as stackoverflow is a programming Q/A site.

Answer (score 0):

The received first INV may be proceed to establish the call by the SIP Proxy, whereas the received second INV maybe rejected by a 4xx response. But since SIP is session based it is also possible that the Proxy can establish both calls. But one call should be in hold state. Only one call will ve active.

Comment: The SIP proxy is the main player for this scenario. Not the clients.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely behaviour is that the SIP user agents would display a new incoming call.

Since they would also both have an outgoing call in progress it would be up to the user as to whether they would answer the incoming call or ignore it and persist with their original outgoing call.

The crucial point is that the two INVITE requests are independent. It would be the same as if two people called each other on their mobile phones simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 3261 section 14.2 says

> A UAS that receives an INVITE on a dialog while an INVITE it had sent
>   on that dialog is in progress MUST return a 491 (Request Pending)
>   response to the received INVITE.

So, I think both the parties will generate 491 response to each other. But I am still not sure as both of these INVITE will be part of different dialogs and standard mentions on the same dialog.